# Vagrant shared-folders across multiple OS's with Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, vagrant, shared-directory

I'm using vagrants virtualbox plugin to share a directory across OSX and Windows. In windows I am using cygwin.

In my vagrant file I share the filepath like this:

```
config.vm.define "windows" do |windows|
    ...... stuff here ....
    windows.vm.synced_folder "/Users/user/ProjectDir", "/Users/user/ProjectDir"
  end
```

The problem is that when I open that directory on Windows (using cygwin's prompt), cygwin routes it to `/cygdrive/c/Users/user/ProjectDir`

The application that shares this directory on windows *has* to use the path `/Users/user/ProjectDir` and it *has* to use cygwin.

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Vagrant on Windows at all but I think technically symbolic links should help.

In Cygwin Terminal (mintty): `ln -s /cygdrive/c/Users/user/ProjectDir /Users/user/ProjectDir`.

> NOTE: This may not work as AFAIK `vboxsf` (the default Vagrant synced folder option - VirtualBox Shared Folder) has problems working with symbolic links. But you can try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The issue is that the `/Users/user/ProjectDir` directory is never even created inside Windows in the first place, so I'm don't think I can make a symbolic link to a directory that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsync with cygwin to access your shared directory. Refer these links

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html

https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-5-rsync.html

There is an example here about syncing data between a linux and windows system [here](http://backup.programtech.eu/node/20). This may come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and this works on my desktop.

```
config.vm.synced_folder "D:/folder", "/folder"
```